# unable to open QtCreator

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, qt, qt-creator

I installed QtCreator 5.8 by download Qt.run file(Qt 5.8.0 for Linux 64-bit)  from Qt offical site( http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2).

I installed by command line(sudo ./qt.run).Installation done successfully.

When i tried to open qt-creator from command line.

```
ERROR:
./qtcreator: symbol lookup error: /opt/Qt5.8.0/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk3.so: undefined symbol: g_type_ensure.
```

Host : ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe how you installed QtCreator.

Comment: @cal H. Problem solved. I download qt-sdk package through synaptic.Then it starts working

Answer (score 2):

This is just a platform theme, simply delete the file `/opt/Qt5.8.0/Tools/QtCreator/lib/Qt/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk3.so` and it should start.

You will have to tackle another problem regarding `"/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found"`, which can be solved by installing this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.7-dev
```